# Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugging is not working

Tags: visual-c++

I want to use the remote debugger for VS2017.

But every time I started it on my VS machine I got the following error message:

"Could not launch debugger. Check the Debug settings.."

Do you have any hint, where can I get more information about the problem, like remote debgger not started, Proxy problem, settings... ?
Or how I can fix it ?

I setup the remote debugging connection for VS2017 on two Windows 10 machines.
On the remote debugging machine I started the tool by execution of msvmon.exe (by sharing the folder location on the machine, on which VS2017 is running).
It seems to run without any error, since a window was open with displays the machine name and the Port.

I copied then this information in the Remote Server Name field for the Visual studio debugger. I tried it with and without port number).

I also copied the debugger application to the same folder of the remote debugging machine, as it is on the VS machine.

After that I started the Remote Debugging session and the error message is shown.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue. The problem was that the remote command parameter was not set. :-(